# can i receive an information another app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i'm studying iOS programming.

i have a program, i will call this program is `aProgram`.

and i don't have any source about `aProgram`, but my iphone was installed this application.

and i make a program called `myProgram`.

there's a button in `myProgram`. when i clicked the button, aProgram will be launched.

and yes i use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];`

url is parse by json code.

anyway i clicked the button, `aProgram` is launched.

`aProgram` has a function, which is write mail.

`aProgram`'s that button is clicked, it sends to server to information
(i heard that would be a json code too)

and my question is

when i click that write mail button in `aProgram`,

can `myProgram` be caught any data from `aProgram`?

if it can, tell me how can i do that. help me

Comment: No, you generally can't do that unless `aProgram` decides to explicitly send some information back to `myProgram` using the same mechanism.

Comment: Intercepting data that is not intended for your program is something malware does...so it doesn't make sense for this to be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Apple can, but you can't.

Comment: Since iOS apps inhabit a sandbox, they can't read files on other apps' sandboxes. They can't detect events, network activity, or anything else.

Comment: And even if it were not sandboxed, your app would be rejected.